# How to get jquery preventDefault style behavior in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Quite simply, I'm am having trouble figuring out how to emulate/duplicate preventDefault()'s behavior in IE11. 
Here's my simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VUUph/

```
$(".rateclick").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

It works in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE11.  How can a get preventDafult() or equivalent to work in IE?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The problem here is with jsFiddle.  It's loading your code in an iFrame, and there's a jQuery bug that is making your JavaScript code not run in jQuery.  Try to go to http://jsfiddle.net/VUUph/show/ in IE 11 or change the jQuery version to "1.x (edge)", and you'll see it works fine.

Comment: Even when you take it out of the iframe it does not work.
In ie11, clicking the radio button, unchecks the previously checked button(part of the default radio button behavior) but the other browsers, no checked states are changed.

Comment: Hmm... didn't notice that.  Now that sounds like an IE issue.  See: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10494

Answer (score 0):

Set the "returnValue" property of the `event` object to `false`.

You have to check for the presence of the "preventDefault" property before trying to call it as a function, or IE will give you an exception. You can however always set "returnValue" and non-IE browsers will ignore it.

```
if ("preventDefault" in e)
  e.preventDefault();
e.returnValue = false;
```

Note that IE (old versions, at least) uses a global `event` object, so handlers should be written to pick that up if the event parameter isn't passed.

Comment: jQuery should take care of this for you.  `e` is not a native event, it's a jQuery event object.

Comment: I found very similiar suggestions when searching for the problem.  And I tried that solution in the fiddle, the second set of radio buttons check for preventDefaults existance, and when it doesn't find it, i changes the returnValue property of the global event.--but alas it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your code.  You are using jQuery to bind the event.  The `e` parameter is *not* a native event object, it's a jQuery event object.  It wraps around the native one and normalizes around cross-browser differences.

When you call `e.preventDefault();`, you are telling jQuery to operate on the native event object.  It will figure out whether to call `preventDefault()` or set `e.returnValue` for you.

The issue here is with jsFiddle itself!  It uses iframes to run your code, and jQuery 1.10.1 cannot access this iframe (in IE 11).  It's a jQuery bug.  The solution is to change the jQuery version to "1.x (edge)" since this bug was fixed in newer versions of jQuery.

You can also access append `/show` to the jsFiddle URL (like so: http://jsfiddle.net/VUUph/show/) to have it run your code as a full page not not in an iframe.  This too will fix the problem.

**EDIT**: In IE 11, it seems like `e.preventDefault()` will make it clear all the radio buttons.  This seems like a bug in IE, as per this (similar not not the same) jQuery bug: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10494

Answer (score 0):

I thought it would benefit everyone that sees this to learn the workaround I'm came up with.
In this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UMcV3/show/

```
$(".defaulttest").click(function(e)
{
e.preventDefault();
});
$(".labeltest").click(function(e)
{
e.preventDefault();
});
```

In one set, I put the prevent default on the inputs themselves -- this does not work.
But in the second set I put the prevent default on the labels -- this does work.
So to work around this issue, put the function on the label and then use some css to hide the actual input as exampled here: http://jsfiddle.net/g9Md2/show/